# Ошибка SQL с datetime

Tags: mysql

Массив where:

```
$wheres = '(app_id = '1' AND end_date >= '.$end_date.' AND start_date < '.$end_date.' AND rights != 1 AND users_group = 0) OR (app_id = '1' AND rights != 1 AND users_group = '1')';
```

где `end_date` = 2019-01-10 17:26:06

получаю ошибку

```
Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`17:26:06` AND `start_date` < `2019-01-10` `17:26:06` AND `rights` != 1 AND `use' at line 3 - Invalid query
```

Как правильно сформировать массив?

Comment: Попробуйте WHERE DATE(end_date) = '2019-01-10', а вообще похоже у вас проблема с фоматом даты.

Comment: Во первых текстовые значения могут быть только в обычных одинарных или двойных кавычках. Но не в обратных, как у вас. В обратных кавычках задаются имена колонок и таблиц. И конечно дату и время надо задавать в виде одной текстовой константы `'2019-01-10 17:26:06'`. Собственно вы это похоже и пытаетесь сделать, только в переменной у вас походу хранится что то странное

Comment: Я ставлю одинарные кавычки. Дата в переменной имеет вид строчки 2019-01-10 17:26:06 Как правильно мне это указать в массиве?

Comment: *получаю ошибку* Да не сообщение об ошибке надо показывать, а то, что насобиралось в переменной `$wheres`. И тег соответственно поменяйте - на PHP.